# How to pass data to a C++0x lambda function that will run in a different thread?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

**Important update**: Apparently I drew the wrong conclusion when I asked this question. Thanks to the responses I found out the lambda function `[=]()` does work fine in a multithreaded scenario. My apologies for posing this confusing question. Please vote to close, as it was a non-issue.

---

In our company we've written a library function to call a function asynchronously in a separate thread. It works using a combination of inheritance and template magic. The client code looks as follows:

```
DemoThread thread;
std::string stringToPassByValue = "The string to pass by value";
AsyncCall(thread, &DemoThread::SomeFunction, stringToPassByValue);
```

Since the introduction of lambda functions I'd like to use it in combination with lambda functions. I'd like to write the following client code:

```
DemoThread thread;
std::string stringToPassByValue = "The string to pass by value";
AsyncCall(thread, [=]()
{
    const std::string someCopy = stringToPassByValue;
});
```

**Update**: contrary to what I first believed when asking this question, this code works fine.

<strike>Now, with the Visual C++ 2010 this code doesn't work. What happens is that the `stringToPassByValue` is not copied. Instead **the "capture by value" feature passes the data by reference**. The result is that if the function is executed after `stringToPassByValue` has gone out of scope, the application crashes as its destructor is called already.</strike>

So I wonder: **is it possible to pass data to a lambda function as a copy**?

**Note**: One possible solution would be to modify our framework to pass the data in the lambda parameter declaration list, as follows:

```
DemoThread thread;
std::string stringToPassByValue = "The string to pass by value";
AsyncCall(thread, [=](const std::string stringPassedByValue)
{
    const std::string someCopy = stringPassedByValue;
}
, stringToPassByValue);
```

However, this solution is so verbose that our original function pointer solution is both shorter and easier to read.

**Update**: The full implementation of `AsyncCall` is too big to post here. In short, what happens is that the `AsyncCall` template function instantiates a template class holding the lambda function. This class is derived from a base class that contains a virtual `Execute()` function, and upon an `AsyncCall()` call, the function call class is put on a call queue. A different thread then executes the queued calls by calling the virtual `Execute()` function, which is polymorphically dispatched to the template class which then executes the lambda function.

Comment: Sounds like a bug somewhere: `[=]` is defined to capture by copy. Are you sure that in your real code, stringToPassByValue is a `std::string`, and not a pointer?

Comment: Also, how is `AsyncCall` defined? Unless it's a template, I don't know how to pass lambdas around, because they have funny types.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: I am 100% sure it is not a pointer. You are right in that this seems like a bug in the Visual C++ compiler, but it might also be that it was never intended to be used in a multithreaded situation, or that there is another alternative

Comment: @Steve Jessop: I added an update in which I explain how the AsyncCall function is implemented.

Comment: @Dimitri: does it work if you don't use threads?

Comment: LOL, good thing there were no actual answers then :)

Comment: @Dmitri: "You are right in that this seems like a bug in the Visual C++ compiler" - well, I thought it was more likely it was a bug elsewhere in your code. Pleased to see we're both wrong ;-)

Comment: @Steve Jessop: :-) Well, it's a pretty complicated construction I've got here, with templates and polymorphism mixed together, which made stepping through the code a somewhat confusing experience. Furthermore because of this complexity, I almost expected it would not work, pushing me to the wrong conclusion.